Movie with zombie young girl attacking parents
I'm trying to look up a movie I saw a couple weeks back (December 2017).
I just saw it for a couple mins which looked like it was the opening scene of a zombie movie.
It was morning and a couple was in their bedroom. There was a girl zombie outside the their door and when the door was opened, she jumped onto the man and bit him on the neck. The woman managed to push the zombie girl out of the bedroom while the man kept bleeding and started to change. Then the zombie man tried to bite her and she got away. She came outside their house and drove with blood stains from her husband when a neighbor saw her and shouted not to get close.
That was all. The movie was in English and seems like a U.S. production. I appreciate your help!

Sounds like the beginning of the Dawn of the Dead remake. 

"Ana goes home to her peaceful suburban residence, but she is unpleasantly surprised the morning that follows when her husband is brutally attacked by her zombified neighbor. In the chaos of her once picturesque neighborhood, Ana flees and stumbles upon a police officer named Kenneth, along with more survivors who decide that their best chances of survival would be found in the deserted Crossroads Shopping Mall. When supplies begin running low and other trapped survivors need help, the group comes to the realization that they cannot stay put forever at the Shopping Mall, and devise a plan to escape."

Here's the scene:




oh my god. That's it! That's the movie. Thank you!
I didn't think anybody would get it based on my poor description of it.
